# Function that counts down as a subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, timer

I have a problem in which I am running a Tkinter GUI program (a quiz game). While the user has a choice of 4 buttons and can choose one, I need a countdown timer that will change the question when the time is zero. I need it as a subprocess or separate thread because the user will not be able to choose an answer otherwise.

This is different from other questions about timers because the answers to those questions include `[Object] = threading.Timer(numCount, callback)`, but the Timer does not return its value as it counts.

Is there any way to do this? I have already tried multiple methods, including the threading module, and the pygame clock (:D).

Comment: No, you don't need a subprocess or a thread. A timer is trivial to implement in tkinter with the `after` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreading might not be necessary: You can use the `after` method to change the question when time has passed, while keeping your GUI reactive:

In the following example, the question changes every 10 seconds.

```
import tkinter as tk


def countdown(t):
    cdn['text'] = f'{t}'
    if t > 0:
        root.after(1000, countdown, t-1)


def change_question(idx):
    lbl['text'] = questions[idx % 2]
    root.after(10000, change_question, idx+1)
    countdown(10)


def clickme(t):
    print(f"{lbl['text']} : {t}")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    questions = ['Is multi-threading necessary?', 'Is simple better than complicated?']
    root = tk.Tk()
    bt1 = tk.Button(root, text='Yes', command=lambda: clickme('Yes'))
    bt2 = tk.Button(root, text='No', command=lambda: clickme('No'))
    bt3 = tk.Button(root, text='Maybe', command=lambda: clickme('Maybe'))
    bt4 = tk.Button(root, text='No Idea', command=lambda: clickme('No Idea'))
    lbl = tk.Label(root, text='')
    cdn = tk.Label(root, text='')
    cdn.pack()

    lbl.pack()
    bt1.pack()
    bt2.pack()
    bt3.pack()
    bt4.pack()
    change_question(0)
    root.mainloop()
```

#### sample output:

```
Is multi-threading necessary? : No
Is simple better than complicated? : Yes
```

Comment: You could make the call to `after` a bit less complicated by removing the lambda: `root.after(10000, change_question, idx+1)`. The button commands can also be shortened a bit since `t` is a constant in every case: `Button(..., command=lambda: clickme('Yes'))`.

Comment: Good points, thank you. I did not know args could be passed with `after` outside of a lambda construct.

Comment: @Reblochon-Masque This I know. But I want the current time count to appear in the top right corner, and the after method cannot implement that. Is there another way?

Comment: Sorry, I added a countdown label that also uses the`after` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use `signal`:

```
def myfunc(sig, frame):
    print("timer fired")

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, myfunc)
signal.alarm(4) # seconds
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Nothing is printed and the process seems to be running continuously because the program does not close.